# AWS S3 cmd to automatically make file public while uploading

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

**Description:**

Hi, I am trying to ssh a linux server and from that I am trying to upload a file to S3 bucket using AWS cli, and its working fine.

```
AWS S3 cp /path/to/file s3://sample_bucket --profile=user1
```

**Problem:**

But while uploading the file, i want to make that file public too. Is there any command to make the file public, if so then please correct the above given command.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can set the Access Control List (ACL) while copying an object. So your command would become.

`aws s3 cp /path/to/file s3://sample_bucket --acl public-read`

You'll also want to check the buckets Permissions tab and review the Manage public access control lists (ACLs) settings.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. I just did this the other day but with their `sync` command, same argument works there, too.

Comment: how do you get the public url for the object as well?